# HTML CSS responsively stacking images in two columns

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is making [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_opacity) type of effect to stack in two columns responsively. ( So that when I resize my window, images won't be streched )

And I can't do it. Could you please guide my on how can I achieve this effect? I can't even make two images to stack side by side on that fiddle, they seem to always stack in one column like this.

[image]

I've tried using Boostrap with container and col-lg-6, had no success.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added a snipet. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inline the block and make sure the width is set such that two or more windows are able to fit. Simples.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 40%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .image {
      opacity: 1;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      transition: .5s ease;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .middle {
      transition: .5s ease;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
    
    .container:hover .image {
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
    
    .container:hover .middle {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .text {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 16px 32px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Opacity with Box</h2>
    <p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>
    
    <div class="container">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">John Doe</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="text">John Doe</div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Re: other answers: bear in mind that floats are generally discouraged as an issue of best practice where other solutions are available, and may lead to unexpected results. Flexbox is overkill for this problem and risks unnecessarily breaking compatibility with older browsers, though is a useful thing to learn.

Comment: As this question deals with layout, I think flexbox (and grid) should be encouraged, unless the OP has restrictions preventing this.

Comment: Grid is still very new technology and to my knowledge is not yet supported by a very significant browser-base. Using flexbox is often of value for larger projects, particularly where the developer has sufficient knowledge to implement polyfills etc; ditto grid, in many ways. But generally speaking for beginners with simple problems I find simple solutions more appropriate and favour an approach that prioritises learning the basics solidly and properly first.

Comment: For sure, I agree, and your answer is perfectly correct for OP's question. I think Flexbox is quickly becoming the basics though.. and as for Grid, here is a good article about support and fallbacks https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/07/04/is-it-really-safe-to-start-using-css-grid-layout/

Comment: I had to center these images after I made them stack in two columns. Had a lot of trouble centering a `float:left` value, and ended up using your suggestion which is much easier to center. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help, thanks. Sometimes the simple solutions are best :).

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your image containers in a div with `display: flex`

*updated as per comment*

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">John Doe</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">John Doe</div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="container">
    <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">John Doe</div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="container">
    <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">John Doe</div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="container">
    <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">John Doe</div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="container">
    <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">John Doe</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need images to stack in two columns only. This makes them stack in n columns resizing them responsively. It's nice to know there is a way to make such thing, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Deividas Answer updated. A good guide to flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to use **float:left** but the you should add another elements wich resets the flow of the document, so that element should have the **clear: both** property.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    float: left
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://img.draugas.lt/forumas/veidukai/973676.gif" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text">John Doe</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p style="clear: both;"></p>
  
</body>
</html>
```